# Logic to divide any integer number into same five parts

Tags: php, logic

Want to divide random integer number into equal five parts. And insert those values into array. Can any one tell me the logic for that.

Eg. I have 15 as my number. After dividing. It should generate the array as below.

```
   $myArray = array('3','6','9','12','15');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if the number is not a multiple of 5?

Comment: What if the number isn't divisible by 5, like, say, 2?

Comment: It should round those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide and create a loop to fill the array...

```
$total = 15;
$divide = 5;

$base = $total / $divide;

$arr = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= $divide; $i++) {
    $arr[] = round($i * $base);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function getParts($number, $parts)
{
    return array_map('round', array_slice(range(0, $number, $number / $parts), 1));
}

print_r(getParts(15, 5));
```

**Explanation:** [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) generates the array of values starting with `0`, ending when it reaches `$number` and using the step `$number/$parts`. It will get `$parts+1` floating point numbers. [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) removes the first item (which is always `0`). [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) applies the function [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) to each element to get the nearest integer.